# Carousel schema in Microsoft adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm unable to get the adaptive cards schema for carousel. When I have gone through docs I found one schema but when using that got the message saying upgrade to new schema. But I didn't see any where the new JSON schema for adaptive cards carousel.

Answer (score 2):

There is no carousel in Adaptive Cards (yet...)

This link provides the element collections that are available at present for Adaptive Cards

http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/

You could always raise this as a feature request over on the GitHub site
https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues

Answer (score 0):

An adaptive card is actually an attachment that you have in a simple text. Now you can have a carousel of adaptive cards but not carousels IN adaptive cards. I'll attach a link so that you can create a carousel of adaptive cards referring to it:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/2507

Comment: Image Carousel component can be added now in adaptive cards. Please check this Image Carousel template in this adaptive cards builder                                                                    
https://diybuilder.in/adaptive-cards-builder/templates.php

Answer (score 0):

Image Carousel component can be added now in adaptive cards.
Please check the Image Carousel template in this adaptive cards builder,

https://diybuilder.in/adaptive-cards-builder/templates.php